# Empty directories with Setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, software-distribution

How to include *empty* directories in a source or built Python distribution with Setuptools?

Directory layout:

```
project
├─ src
|  └─ package
|     ├─ __main__.py
|     ├─ data.tsv
|     ├─ module.py
|     └─ plugins
├─ tests
|  └─ test_module.py
├─ MANIFEST.in
├─ README.rst
└─ setup.py
```

setup.py:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="project",
    version="0.1.0",
    url="https://project.org/",
    author="Maggyero",
    author_email="maggyero@project.org",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages("src"),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

MANIFEST.in:

```
graft src
graft tests
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

Currently the *empty* `plugins` directory is not included.

Comment: As a workaround, maybe just include an empty placeholder file in the plugins directory?

Comment: @AKX I know the workaround, but is there a proper way?

Comment: The proper way is not to include empty directories at all and only create them when needed.

Comment: Thanks @phd, could you write this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the proper way is not to include empty directories at all and only create them when needed.

Comment: Is it the reason why PyPA suggests to include an \_\_init\_\_.py file in the packaging documentation [Creating and discovering plugins](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-namespace-packages): "For the “namespace sub-package” approach to work, the plugin packages must omit the \_\_init\_\_.py for your top-level package directory (myapp in this case) and include the namespace-package style \_\_init\_\_.py in the namespace sub-package directory (myapp/plugins)."?

Comment: No, namespace sub-package omit top-level `__init__.py` to avoid overriding it.

Comment: They say *include*, not *omit*, for the namespace sub-package. They say omit only for the top-level namespace package. Which I find weird, unless if it is for allowing the namespace sub-package to be included in the distribution by Setuptools (in this case the \_\_init\_\_.py would be a placeholder file).

Comment: Then I'm not sure. I can create namespace packages but I don't know how they are implemented in `pip` and `setuptools`.

Comment: Actually there are two standard namespace packages: [native namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) (no \_\_init\_\_.py file) and [`pkgutil`-style namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages) (an \_\_init\_\_.py file with this single line: `__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)`). Contrary to native namespace packages, `pkgutil`-style namespace packages are not empty so they are always included in Python distributions.

Comment: So I assume that is why they suggest to use a `pkgutil`-style namespace sub-package for `myapp.plugins` (and a native namespace package for `myapp` since here the \_\_init\_\_.py file is not needed as the package is not empty anyway).